# Undoing bundle clean

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

I'm working on a computational servers that uses `rvm` and `bundler` to manage system gems. Yesterday after getting some odd gem dependency errors I ran `bundle clean --force`, admittedly rashly. This claims to have removed many gems, though I don't know that it has entirely (see below).

`bundle` and `gem` now don't see the locally installed gems. If I look in the gem path (`/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems`) all of the files and folders appear to still be present. Also, now when I try to re-install gems that already exist on the server, if I was not the original installer, I get permission errors as the files already exist.

Is there any way to get `gem` and/or `bundle` to see these gems, without reinstalling each one manually?

Comment: The *whole point* of `bundler` is that you *shouldn't need to* install any gems manually! You should be placing each dependency in the `Gemfile`, rather than installing via `gem install <gem-name>`. I would take this as an opportunity to define all dependencies for the project properly.

Comment: We use several gems developed in-house which we install with each new version. These have to be installed manually, as we don't run a locally-hosted gem repository.

The dependencies are all in Gemfiles, but at the moment if I run `bundle install` it will complain about missing gems, but if I run `bundle install` I get permissions errors because the files exist.

Comment: *"These have to be installed manually, as we don't run a locally-hosted gem repository."* - Running a local gemserver is [quite easy](https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox), or you can alternatively use a [paid host](https://gemfury.com/). Or, if neither option is feasible for you, why not reference the (private) github repo directly in the `Gemfile`? However you go about it, there should honestly be no need to install gems manually like that. Within a large project, this will likely lead to version dependency problems down the line.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment -- "The dependencies are all in Gemfiles" ... So why do you need to `gem install <gem-name>`? If everything is in the `Gemfile`, then `bundle` is all you need.

Comment: Also: *"...if I was not the original installer"* - This is even more worrying! Do you have multiple users installing gems manually, on a production server??! You could *make this work* by putting all users under the same *group*, and managing permissions that way, but again - you really ought not to be doing this.

Comment: I might suggest running a local gemserver, but currently we don't, which makes it difficult in this case. I have the *current* versions of the gems installed, which I did manually. However existing projects may use old versions of the gems, which I could install manually from gitlab, but I don't want to do. As I've said twice now, I can't easily run many `bundle` commands because it doesn't recognise gems that exist in the system. Two users install gems via bundler, and we use the rvm group, but the permissions are rw-r--r--

Comment: I don't know... You have a strange setup; I'm not sure what to suggest. My next steps would be to just re-install rvm/bundler to get a clean slate, then ideally set things up properly through `bundle` rather than manual installation. And if you *do* use manual installation, this should be done with an rvm **gemset** rather than globally. You could try messing around with permissions in that folder to get it working, but you may just end up with a more convoluted problem. From prior experience, when `rvm` gets this messed up it's often easier to just `rvm implode` and start again.

Comment: *"I have the current versions of the gems installed"* - But do those versions have dependencies? Are they compatible with all your other libraries, and their dependencies? Maybe... But this is the whole point of using `bundler`; to manage this problem for you :)

Comment: Yes, they do. Dependencies which are managed using bundler...

Comment: I know, usually this would be a lot easier to solve. The combination of versioning with bundle and manual installs is not ideal. I think that's best solved as you suggested by running a gem server. I just hoped that since the gems still exist on the server, there would be some way of restoring. I just don't understand how the current situation works. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @TomLord - thanks for the advice. I've now set up a local gem server using geminabox, so hopefully I'll never again annoy/scare you on SO. Cheers, I owe you a pint

Comment: Haha no worries :) I know it can be a pain to re-set things up, but hopefully it saves you a lot more time in the long run!